# Newbie stuck with jQuery alerts not prompting notifications in browsers

Tags: jquery, html, browser, notifications, alert

I started learning jQuery on thenewboston.com and got stuck after a dozen tutorials. When I was learning JavaScript, I had no problem with alerts and prompts - they would pop up in the browser. I started having problems after I stared learning jQuery.

I have a simple code that should count all the elements on the page and prompt user the number of elements.

For index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Some text.</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectors.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For selectors.js file:

```
var count = $('*').length;
alert(count);
```

jquery.js is filled with code downloaded from the official jQuery site (compressed production version).

The code you see here is provided by thenewboston.com instructor, and I checked it dozens of times for mistakes (the videos appear a bit older, don't know if something drastically changed in the meantime). Also, file architecture is fine. Both jquery.js and selectors.js are within js folder, and index.html is in root.

What I try so far after googling:

- tried Firefox and Chrome
- tinkered with permission settings in both browsers (turned
  notifications off and on)
- tried putting the -script- code within the -head- tags
- tried changing `type="text/javascript"` to
  `type="application/javascript"` within -script- tags

Sorry, I changed <> symbols with -- because I had some formatting issues within bulleted lists.

I tried researching, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I found something similar (I think on stackoverflow even), and the OP managed to find a solution by turning his browser notifications on.

Comment: have you checked the developer console of your browser for errors?

Comment: I don't think you need `selectors.js`. Try removing that.

Comment: I recommend to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. You can see then the output in the developer console. Maybe your browser blocks alert messages if they come to many.

Comment: It worked! What I did: Re-downloaded jquery with Chrome, and put that file instead of the old one. The old one was "downloaded" with Firefox (I was in Starbucks :P). What happened then was that Firefox opened a new tab with all the code and I copy and pasted it to my customly, newly created jquery.js.

This way, I downloaded the real thing and just renamed it... -.-

Sorry for wasting precious time and space...

Comment: And thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 0):

This code works [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/8mpx1zz5/).

```
var count = $('*').length;
alert(count);
```

You can even run it in the dev console, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nvm guys I found a solution...

I was using Firefox when I was downloading jQuery. What happened was that Firefox opened a new tab with all the code after clicking download. I copy-pasted that code to my empty text file and called it jQuery.js.

Now using Chrome, I downloaded it again, and it was the real deal. I just renamed it, and put it in the js folder, and voila. *feeling stupid*

Thx for the answers and effort guys!